# Airflow - Run task if either fails

Tags: airflow

I would like to have a dag in which if there is an error in any task, it should automatically perform a task to "reset" the table and end the process. Example:

```
#Task that needs to be performed if any of the above fails
drop_bq_op = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='drop_bq',
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    allow_large_results=True,
    bql="""DELETE FROM dataset.table1 WHERE ID IS NOT NULL""",
    bigquery_conn_id='gcp',
    dag=dag)

#task1
MsSql = MsSqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='import',
    mssql_conn_id=mssql,
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcp',
    sql=sql_query,
    bucket=nm_bucket,
    filename=nm_arquivo,
    schema_filename=sc_arquivo,
    dag=dag)

#task2
Google = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='gcs_to_bq',
    bucket='bucket',
    source_objects=[nm_arquivo],
    destination_project_dataset_table=dataset_bq_tbl,
    schema_fields=sc_tbl_bq,
    source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition=wrt_disposition,
    time_partitioning=tp_particao,
    cluster_fields=nm_cluster,
    bigquery_conn_id='gcp',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcp',
    dag=dag
)

task_3 = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='test3',
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    allow_large_results=True,
    bql="""select ...""",
    bigquery_conn_id='gcp',
    dag=dag)
```

**UPDATE:** I include this code in my script:

```
def delete_bigquery():
    """query bigquery to get data to import to PSQL"""
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query = "DELETE FROM dataset.table1 WHERE ID IS NOT NULL"
    dataset = client.dataset('dataset')
    table = dataset.table(name='table1')
    job_name = 'delete_{}'.format(uuid.uuid4())
    job = client.run_async_query(job_name, query)
    job.destination = table
    job.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
    job.begin()
    return job.state

cleanup_task = PythonOperator(task_id="cleanup_task",
                              python_callable=delete_bigquery,
                              trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
                              dag=dag)

[gcs_to_bq.set_upstream(import), task_3.set_upstream(gcs_to_bq)] >> cleanup_task
```

And now this error appears when I go up the dag again:

> Broken DAG: [dag.py] Relationships can only be set between Operators;
>   received NoneType

Answer (score 0):

- This is a classical case to employ [`TriggerRules`](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules)
- You can create your *`cleanup_task`* and *hook it* with all upstream tasks (that need to be *cleaned-up*) and assign [`trigger_rule="one_failed"`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L191) to it

> ```
> # refer code here https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/trigger_rule.py#L28
> from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
> ..
> cleanup_task = PythonOperator(dag_id="..",
>                               task_id="cleanup_task"
>                               ..
>                               trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED
>                               ..)
> ..
> # all tasks that must be cleaned-up should have `cleanup_task` in their downstream
> [my_task_1, my_task_2, my_task_3] >> cleanup_task
> ```

Comment: I´m trying to keep the task sequencing, so I wrote this sequence: "[gcs_to_bq.set_upstream(import), task3.set_upstream(gcs_to_bq)] >> cleanup_task" 
But I have this error message: "Relationships can only be set between Operators; received NoneType"